# How to grab value using XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have this xml from which I am trying to grab the value in the node `<ErrorCode>` after investigating, i found it easier to use XDocument because it cleans any unwanted `\r\n` that the response from an api was giving me.. but now I am not sure how to retrieve that value using XDocument

```
<PlatformResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <ErrorMessage>OAuth Token rejected</ErrorMessage>
  <ErrorCode>270</ErrorCode>
  <ServerTime>2012-06-19T03:53:34.4558857Z</ServerTime>
</PlatformResponse>
```

I want to be able to take advantage of this call to get the value

```
 XDocument xmlResponse = XDocument.Parse(response);
```

I can't use XmlDocument because it does not clean the XML as it is doing it XDocument

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have defined the Namespace, try the following code:

```
    XDocument xmlResponse = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");
    //Or you can use XDocument xmlResponse = XDocument.Parse(response)
    XNamespace ns= "http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1";
    var test = xmlResponse.Descendants(ns+ "ErrorCode").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Or if you don't want to use Namespace then:

```
    var test3 = xmlResponse.Descendants()
                .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ErrorCode")
                .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: +1 but I would use `(string)xmlResponse.Descendants(ns+ "ErrorCode").FirstOrDefault();` to get a null back if error code is not present.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath structure to get the value somethink like this

```
string errorcode= xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("PlatformResponse/ErrorCode").InnerText
```

or this

```
string result = xmlResponse.Descendants("ErrorCode").Single().Value;
```

Comment: I don't want to use XmlDocument, I need to use XDocument because it parses it and cleans the extra \r\n s that the api is returning....

Comment: it not really mattter how you call your variable it should still work

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("YouXMLPath");

var query = from d in doc.Root.Descendants()
            where d.Name.LocalName == "ErrorCode"
            select d.Value;
```